# MySQL: search in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

how to search in two columns for string:

user table: (structure)

```
id     first_name     last_name
1         John         Adam
2         Chris        Pratt
3         Tom          keene
4         Sarah        April
5         Nina         Lora
```

how to search in both "first_name" and "last_name" for string, ex:

```
search phrase "pra"
return 
uid => 2
```

thanks,

Comment: `Where first_name LIKE 'pra*' or last_name LIKE 'pra*' ` unless I'm confusing syntax or misreading your question.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name = "" AND last_name = "";`. Real basic question. Read tutorials before posting here. If you mean 'a part of' you have to use: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name LIKE "%pra%" AND last_name LIKE "%pra%";`. Replace `AND` with `||` if only one column has to match your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the overhead of concat to be faster than two full text or searches.  Assuming case insensitive...

```
SELECT ID 
FROM tableName
WHERE CONCAT(First_name,Last_Name) like '%PRA%'
```

OR

This is the typical method.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableName
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%PRA%'
OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%PRA%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To query two separate columns for a value you need to put the columns in the SELECT statement separated by a comma and then specify the value for comparison in the WHERE statement:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM tableName 
WHERE first_name LIKE '%PRA%' OR last_name LIKE '%PRA%';
```